# Why the constant() solution is more efficient than the easier one in "FP in Scala" 5.8?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I am looking at exercise 5.8 in book "FP in Scala" and the question is:

"Generalize ones slightly to the function constant, which returns an infinite Stream of a given value."

```
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A]
```

My solution is:

```
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] =
  Stream.cons(a, constant(a))
```

while I refer to the standard solution, it was:

```
// This is more efficient than `cons(a, constant(a))` since it's just
// one object referencing itself.
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = {
  lazy val tail: Stream[A] = Cons(() => a, () => tail) 
  tail
}
```

which says "more efficient", see [here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/laziness/08.answer.scala).

Can I know why is it more efficient? AFAIK, the cons constructor in Streams already marks the head and tail as lazy:

```
def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = { 
  lazy val head = hd 
  lazy val tail = tl 
  Cons(() => head, () => tail) 
}
```

Why do we still need to mark the tail as lazy again? I am not quite understand the point here.

Comment: The difference boils down to possibilities of compiler optimisation. Although the `cons` constructor is lazy, your approach does not allow the compiler to determine that you are actually referencing the same object, where as the first approach does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a comment to @ElBaulP answer than an answer in its own rights but it is too big for a comment.

I think you missed the root of the optimization even though it is explicitly stated in the comment above. The fact that the `val tail` in the `constant` is `lazy` is an implementation detail or rather a trick to make the main source of the optimization possible. And the main source of the optimization is the fact that `tail` is self-referential.

For a moment let's get rid of all the `lazy` stuff. Assume that `Cons` is defined as

```
case class Cons[+A](h: A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

and let's define `constant` as

```
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = {
   val tailFunc: () => Stream[A] =  () => tail
   val tail: Stream[A] = Cons(a, tailFunc)
   tail
}
```

Yes, this is a syntactically invalid program because `tailFunc` uses `tail` defined only in the next line. But imagine Scala can compile that. I think now it is quite clear that such an implementation of `constant` will only create one instance of class `Cons` per call and that instance will be used no matter how long you try to iterate over the returned stream.

What defining `tail` as `lazy` allows is just to make the code logically equivalent to the above one compile without errors. From the implementation point of view it is similar to something like that:

```
class Lazy[A](var value:A)

def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = {
   val lazyTail: Lazy[Stream[A]] = new Lazy(null)
   // this tailFunc works because lazyTail is already fixed and can be safely 
   // captured although lazyTail.value will be changed
   val tailFunc: () => Stream[A] =  () => lazyTail.value 
   lazyTail.value = new Stream(a, tailFunc)
   lazyTail.value
}
```

This code does not exactly matches actual `lazy` implementation in many details because it is actually eager but I think it shows that you don't really need `lazy` to make the optimization work (but at the cost of using a `var`, which Scala compiler does anyway inside its real, more complicated `lazy` implementation).

In your naive implementation

```
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] =  Stream.cons(a, constant(a))
```

lazy evaluation of `tail` allows you to not fail immediately with stack overflow because of recursive calls of `constant` from itself. But still when you do `constant(whatever).tail`, the `tail` is being evaluated so the `constant` method is called once again and a new `Cons` object is created. And this will happen every time `tail` is called on new `head`.

To re-state it once again, `lazy val tail` is just a trick to allow `tail` to reference itself at creation and the really important part is the fact that `tail` references itself which allows to use only one object for iteration rather than one object per each next `.tail` call.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation, I only had the intuition of how it worked, but didn't knew the why, now it is clear to me. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

**I think** it is because with the lazy implementation, you are creating the object only once, and memoizing it, so when you call `constant`, you are referring to the same object over and over again, something like this:

```
tail -----
  ^------'
```

With your implementation (That is the same I came across while reading the book), you are creating new objects every time you call the function. So if you call multiple times your implementation, you have:

```
Stream.cons(a, Stream.cons(a, Stream.cons(a, constant(a))))
```

Let see it with an example:

```
def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = { println("CALLED"); cons(a, constant(a)) }

// This is more efficient than `cons(a, constant(a))` since it's just
// one object referencing itself.
def constant_1[A](a: A): Stream[A] = {
   lazy val tail: Stream[A] = Cons(() ⇒ a, () ⇒ tail)
   println("CALLED_1")
   tail
  }

println(s"Cons ${Stream.constant_1(0).take(10).toListFast}")
println(s"Cons ${Stream.constant(0).take(10).toListFast}")
```

Above code produces the following output:

```
CALLED_1
Cons List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
CALLED
Cons List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

As you can see, the `println` statement of the lazy implementation is only called once.

You can see @SergGr for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi @EIBaulP, I am a bit confused as this is the Stream.cons implementation:
```
def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
  lazy val head = hd
  lazy val tail = tl
  Cons(() => head, () => tail)
}
```
So I guess the recursive calls are already laziness, right? Why we still need to manually declare the tail as lazy?

Comment: @injoy, can you write that piece of code on your question? it is hard to read here.

Comment: Hi @EiBaulP, can you add the 'println("CALLED_A") inside the tail function? lazy val tail: Stream[A] = {println("CALLED_1") Cons(() ⇒ a, () ⇒ tail)} and see what will happen?